# How can i add some nodes in my diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I want to create such a diagramm:
[image]

This is my diagram at the moment:

[image]

1: So i want to mark my **x** and **y** axis **labels** with a light grey box.

2: I want to create an extra a label. (This should be the height of my rectangluar in our case value 18) Written in red with a light red filled box. Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{%
  every axis title/.append style={font=\mdseries},
  every label/.append style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
  every axis/.append style={font=\bfseries\boldmath}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}
    [
        enlarge x limits=false,
        no marks,
        grid=none,
        xmin=1e4, xmax=1e8,
        ymin=0, ymax=150,       
        title= Amplituden Spektrum $\sigma_{x}$,
        ylabel={$\sigma_{a}$},
        xlabel={$N$},    
        grid =none, %Hauptgitter grid = minor, %
        extra y ticks  = {35},
        %extra y tick labels  = {}, %Beschriftung weg
        samples=50, %Function (red curve)
        domain=0.125:1e6, %Function (red curve)  
     ]
    %\addplot+[const plot] table[x=countb,y=amplitudea] {3.dat}; %step stairs 
    \addplot+[draw=red,mark=none,domain=1e5:1e6,dashed] {100*(1e6/x)^(1/5)}; 
    \draw[orange,dashed] ({axis cs:50045,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1}) -- ({axis cs:50045,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0});
    \draw[dashed,green] ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,34.385735235}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,34.385735235});          
    \draw [draw=red,thick] (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:100000,18.385735235);
    \addplot+[domain=1e6:1e7,no marks] {100};

    %********

    %********

\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format the x- and y-tick labels use the keys `x tick label style` and `y tick label style`. To add the red number 18, use a `\node` command with coordinates in the coordinate system of the `axis` environment.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{%
  every axis title/.append style={font=\mdseries},
  every label/.append style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
  every axis/.append style={font=\bfseries\boldmath}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}
    [enlarge x limits=false,
     no marks,
     grid=none,
     xmin=1e4, xmax=1e8,
     ymin=0, ymax=150,       
     title= Amplituden Spektrum $\sigma_{x}$,
     xlabel={$N$},    
     ylabel={$\sigma_{a}$},
     x tick label style={fill=gray!20}, %<<<<<<<<<<<
     y tick label style={fill=gray!20}, %<<<<<<<<<<<
     grid =none,
     extra y ticks  = {35},
     samples=50,
     domain=0.125:1e6
    ]
    \addplot+[draw=red,mark=none,domain=1e5:1e6,dashed] {100*(1e6/x)^(1/5)}; 
    \draw[orange,dashed] ({axis cs:50045,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1})
                      -- ({axis cs:50045,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0});
    \draw[dashed,green]  ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,34.385735235})
                      -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,34.385735235});         
    \draw[draw=red,thick] (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:100000,18.385735235);
    \addplot+[domain=1e6:1e7,no marks] {100};
    \node[fill=red!20,text=red] at (axis cs:20000,10) {18}; %<<<<<<<<<<<
  \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `semilogaxis` environment, add the line

```
 ticklabel style={fill=gray!50},
```

to make your ticks have a gray background. The shade may be adjusted from 50% gray to something lighter or darker. You'll have a problem of the vertical tick `0` overlapping the horizontal tick `10^4`.

To add the extra red node, outside the `semilogaxis` environment, but still within the `tikzpicture` environment, add the line

```
 \node[fill=red!20] at (.4,.4) {\color{red}{\textsf{18}}};
```

to add a node in (approximately) the spot you indicated. I've made the font sans-serif, as it looks like that's what you want. You can turn it back to the regular math font by deleting the `\textsf` command.